# Get Machine that executed a certain query on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, audit

is it possible to know the machine that executed a certain query at a certain point of time?

I can get the time and the query executed, using dm_exec_query_stats, but can't seem to find a way related this with the dm_exec_sessions table.

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server Authenticate users/logins not machines, dont think you can get this information from sql server.

Comment: I think you can get it from a profiler trace, if you happen to have one running at the time.

Comment: If you know the exact time the query will run, you could set up sp_Whoisactive to dump to a table.  It logs the hostname of the queries.  This won't help you if it's being called form a central app server, though.

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help:

```
select 
    c.net_transport,
    c.protocol_type,
    c.auth_scheme,
    c.client_net_address,
    r.start_time,
    r.sql_handle,
    s.text
from 
    sys.dm_exec_requests as r inner join sys.dm_exec_connections c on r.session_id = c.session_id 
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) s
order by
    r.start_time desc
```